# Is there a similar thing to items_wrap for the wp_nav_menu() function?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm using wp_nav_menu() to print my navigation to the screen, and I would like to add `data-` attributes to either the `<li>` or the `<a>` within the `<li>`

What I want:

```
<ul>
   <li data-width="width">
      <a>Item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

OR

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a data-width="width">Item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In `wp_nav_menu` there is an attribute called `items_wrap` that will allow you to make the `<ul>` into whatever you want to wrap your items with, I'm wondering if something like this exists for the `<li>` and if not if its possible to make add something like this?

Comment: This [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/227430/12496) has two answers, either a custom walker (more complicated, more control) or a filter (easier, but make sure to unregister it when done)

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was hoping to find!